# Is a Keffiyeh chayav tzitzit?

Tags: halacha, clothing, tzitzis

A [keffiyeh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keffiyeh) is a rectangular piece of fabric traditionally worn by members of the Edot haMizrach and Arabs. However, none of the photos I've seen of B'nei Edot haMizrach and Teimanim wearing these garments (often in a turban rather than the styles associated with B'nei Yishmael) seem to have tzitzit attached to them, despite the fact that they are significantly larger than scarves.

This leads me to wonder: is a keffiyeh *chayav* [obligated in] tzitzit?

Comment: Around what parts of the body is it worn? Just the head?

Comment: Yes it is obligated. And in fact a tallit was originally worn by many the same way as a keffiyeh is worn now. But for some reason the custom changed

Comment: As a side note, your question seems to suggest that you think a scarf would be obligated in _tzitzit_. See [Shulkhan Arukh 10:11](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayyim.10.11?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all)

Comment: @Daniel, no, I realise that a scarf is not chayav, however I figured it was a good reference point for size

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Shulkhan Arukh, OC 10:10](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayyim.10.10?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all) explicitly rules that a turban is exempt from *tzitzit*, even if it covers the majority of the wearer's body.

> מִצְנֶפֶת פְּטוּרָה, אֲפִלּוּ שֶׁל אַרְצוֹת הַמַּעֲרָב שֶׁב' רָאשֶׁיהָ מֻשְׁלָכִים עַל כִּתְפֵיהֶם וְגוּפָם, וְאַף עַל פִּי שֶׁמִּתְכַּסֶה בָּהּ רֹאשׁוֹ וְרֻבּוֹ פָּטוּר, כֵּיוָן שֶׁעִקָּרָהּ לְכַסוֹת הָרֹאשׁ, דִּכְסוּתְךָ אָמַר רַחֲמָנָא וְלֹא כְּסוּת הָרֹאשׁ.
>
> A turban is exempt, even those from the Western lands where both its sides are tossed over their shoulders and body, even though one covers with it one's head and majority [of body] one is exempt, because its main purpose is to cover the head, and the Torah requires "your coverage" but not the coverage of the head.

Comment: I don't think a turban (מצנפת) is the same as a keffiyah. A keffiyah is more actually like a small talit. But it is still prohibited. The idea is that by all opinions it doesn't fit the definition of "atifah" which is to primarily wrap around the body. See Shulchan Aruch HaRav, Orach Chaim, 8:8, 10.  http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=25072&st=&pgnum=63

Comment: @YaacovDeane The reason a מצנפת is exempt from _tzitzit_ is because its purpose is to cover the head rather than the body. This is the case for a _keffiya_. I'm not sure what the technical definitions of either English term are, but I am pretty confident that the reasoning of the SA here applies equally to a _keffiya_ if it is not, in fact, exactly the same thing (or a subset) as a turban.

Comment: That's why you got my up vote. The SA points out with the turban that it also covers the shoulders and the majority of the body. Strictly speaking, that could fall under the definition of 'atifah'. But he sets it apart saying that its intent is to cover the head only. "The Merciful One says to cover you, not the head."

Comment: @YaacovDeane "But it is still prohibited." What is prohibited?

Comment: @DoubleAA Perhaps I should have said 'But it is still not to be used.'. The actual language the Alter Rebbe uses in regard to people who would put tzitzit on these very small talitot is "צריך למחות בידם", it requires protesting. That seems stronger than 'patur'. Women are 'pater' from time bound mitzvot, but you don't protest, for example, when they take up the lulav.

Comment: @YaacovDeane By the way, the _Mishna Berura_ asks the exact opposite question as you. He asks why it's ok to attach an "_atarah_" to a _tallit_ since its purpose seems to be to cover the head. So it's not so simple that a _keffiya_ is like a small _tallit_ but still does not require _tzitzit_ because one doesn't use it for _atifa_. One could say a _tallit_ is like a _keffiya_ and only requires _tzitzit_ despite the _atarah_ because the _atarah_ is just there so you don't confuse the top and bottom of the tallit. http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.10.33?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all